# SQL: the number of distinct registered users within this month

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the number of distinct registered users within this month but SQL still give me 0.

Is there an issue with my code ?

```
select count(distinct id)
from new_users
where month('date') = month(current_date()());
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: `month(current_date()())` is invalid syntax.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct (id), count(*)
from new_users 
where 'date_column' between 'month start date' and 'month end date'
group by id ;
```

OR

```
select distinct (id), count(*)
from new_users 
where month('date') = MONTH(getdate())
group by id  ;
```

Comment: 1) You need a `GROUP BY` here.

Comment: thanks but not correct unfortunately , it give me in aggregated query without group by ...

Comment: @James updated answer

Comment: `distinct` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_ and used together with `select`, just as `select distinct` - to get _distinct rows_. Simply skip those redundant parentheses and simply write `select distinct id, count(*)...` to make code clearer. However, no DISTINCT is needed here since the GROUP BY eliminates the duplicates. I.e. simply do `select id, count(*) ... group by ...`.

Comment: @jarlh or use `row_number`.  

`row_number() over (partition by id) as RN` .... and then  `WHERE RN = 1` in new  select statement

Comment: thanks a lot, however when I tried to use the condition where 'date_column' between 'month start date' and 'month end date', or any format for condition it always give me 0 ! I don't know why !

Comment: @James please send what you have done with your query